# Redirect subdomain with nginx

Tags: url-rewrite, redirect, nginx, https

I have some subdomain from the old site like 123.abc.com and I want to redirect them to abc.com/123. I have installed magento 2.3.2 and nginx as webserver.

Answer (score 0):

We use the following code to redirect one subdomain to another securely.  You may be able to adapt it to something similar...

Put in your sites-enabled conf file:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen 443;

    server_name 123.example.com;

    return 301 https://example.com/123/$request_uri;

}
```